# How to send a mail from a custom form?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I would like to send a mail after a user fill out the form.

The form is OK but now I want to use values in $post to send a mail to a mail address (the mail address of the company)

I'm beginner and I found a lot of tutorials but it's not what I search.

Can someone help me to start ?

Thanks.

```
<?php

namespace Kg\KgContent\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Catalog extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Catalog action
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // 1. POST request : Get catalog data
        $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if (!empty($post)) {
            // Retrieve your form data
            $firstname   = $post['firstname'];
            $lastname    = $post['lastname'];
            $phone       = $post['phone'];

            // Doing-something with...


            // Display the success form validation message
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Votre demande de catalogue a bien été prise en compte');

            // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('/kgkgcontent/index/catalog');

            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        // 2. GET request : Render the catalog page
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller file

```
    <?php
    namespace  Kg\KgContent\Controller\Index;

    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

    class Catalog extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
     protected $storeManager;
     protected $_transportBuilder;
     protected $inlineTranslation;
     protected $_pageFactory;

     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
     {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context); 
     }

     public function execute()
     {      
        $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if (!empty($post)) {
            // Retrieve your form data

                $firstname   = $post['firstname'];
                $lastname    = $post['lastname'];
                $phone       = $post['phone'];

            // Display the succes form validation message
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Sucessfully you had done your returns order !');

            $templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
            $templateVars = array(
                'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
                'firstname' =>$firstname,
                'lastname'    => $lastname,
                'phone'    => $phone
                );
            $from = array('email' => "email@gmail.com", 'name' => 'Name of Sender');
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $to = array('email@gmail.com');
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('email_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($to)
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

            // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $resultRedirect->setUrl('/kgkgcontent/index/catalog');

            return $resultRedirect;
         }


        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
       }
     }
```

You have to create email_templates.xml

> Kg/KgContent\etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="email_template" label="Kg KgContent" file="custom.html" type="html" module="Kg_KgContent" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

Now create email template file custom.html in folder

> Kg/KgContent/view/frontend/email

```
 <!--@subject Email Subject @-->
    <!--@vars
    {"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
    "skin url=\"images/logo_email.gif\" _area='frontend'":"Email Logo Image"}
    @-->
    <!--@styles
    body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
    @-->
    {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
                    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <h1 style="font-size:22px;font-weight:normal;line-height:22px;margin:0 0 11px 0;">{{trans "Hello"}},</h1>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                                {{var firstname}}
                                            </td>
<td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                            {{var lastname}}
                                        </td>
                                        <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                            {{var phone}}
                                        </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA;text-align:center;">
                                <center>
                                    <p style="font-size:12px;margin:0;">
                                        <strong>{{trans "Thank you"}}</strong>
                                    </p>
                                </center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    {{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Kindly response. If you get an answer, mark answer is correct and upvote

Comment: Yes, I try but I have this error 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Kg\KgContent\Controller\Index\Catalog\Interceptor

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: I copy paste the 3 files you get. I can post but it's the same you gave me ;) I set the code on the post

Comment: please change constuctor parent::__construct($context);

Comment: same error i paste your new response...